# Attributing the difference of a variable in different years in a new column based on a certain condition

Tags: r, for-loop, try-catch, rstudio

I have a dataframe which is called df, which looks like the following:

```
country     year    taxrevenue  VAT  CIT
Angola      2006    1000        750  250
Albania     1998    1000        750  250
Albania     2002    1500        1125 375
Albania     2005    1200         900 300
Argentina   1984    1900        1425 475
Argentina   1991    1400        1050 350
Argentina   1995    1600        1200 400
```

What I would like to do is create an additional column for each (tax) column which holds the difference between the tax in one year and the tax in the next, conditional on it being the same country, like so:

```
country     year    dtaxrevenue dvat    dcit
Angola      2006      NA          NA      NA
Albania     1998      NA          NA      NA
Albania     2002     500         375     125
Albania     2005    -300        -225     -75
Argentina   1984      NA         525     175
Argentina   1991    -500        -375    -125
Argentina   1995     200         150      50
```

I had the following in mind:

```
#for each column in df
for(i in 1:ncol(TRcomplete)){
#add a new column
TRcomplete <- cbind(TRcomplete[,i])
# When condition holds..
if(TRcomplete$year[,i]- TRcomplete$year[,i+1] < 0) & TRcomplete$country[,i] == TRcomplete$country[,i+1]{
# try to subtract two values and put them in a new column
try(TRcomplete[,i+1] <- TRcomplete[,i]- TRcomplete[,i+1]
} else {
TRcomplete[,i+1]<-NA
}
```

I am mostly confused as to how to refer to each column. Can anybody offer some help?

Comment: As per your expected output you are looking for **difference between the tax in one year and the tax in the previous**, not _difference between the tax in one year and the tax in the next_. Correct?

Comment: In your desired result, why does Argentina have `dtaxrevenue = 700`?

Comment: Indeed, compared to previous.. Thank you for noticing the error Dan Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mutate_at` is the candidate

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(country, year) %>%  #sort data
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(taxrevenue:CIT), funs(d = . - lag(.)))
```

which gives

```
  country    year taxrevenue   VAT   CIT taxrevenue_d VAT_d CIT_d
1 Albania    1998       1000   750   250           NA    NA    NA
2 Albania    2002       1500  1125   375          500   375   125
3 Albania    2005       1200   900   300         -300  -225  - 75
4 Angola     2006       1000   750   250           NA    NA    NA
5 Argentina  1984       1900  1425   475           NA    NA    NA
6 Argentina  1991       1400  1050   350         -500  -375  -125
7 Argentina  1995       1600  1200   400          200   150    50
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(country = c("Angola", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina"), year = c(2006L, 1998L, 
2002L, 2005L, 1984L, 1991L, 1995L), taxrevenue = c(1000L, 1000L, 
1500L, 1200L, 1900L, 1400L, 1600L), VAT = c(750L, 750L, 1125L, 
900L, 1425L, 1050L, 1200L), CIT = c(250L, 250L, 375L, 300L, 475L, 
350L, 400L)), .Names = c("country", "year", "taxrevenue", "VAT", 
"CIT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just tested and works perfect. Is there anyway I can incorporate a `try`statement in there (I have non-numerical columns in my df)?

Comment: `?mutate_if` might help but for an exact suggestion you may need to share `dput(df)`.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but where would the `?mutate_if` go? I mean, it should not replace the `mutate_at` right?

Comment: try to add `mutate_at(vars(taxrevenue:CIT), funs(as.numeric(as.character(.)))) %>%` as the second line (i.e. before `arrange` statement) in my answer and you should be good to go.

Comment: I was tinkering with this solution because the solution suggested below removed a column that I needed. It works, but I get al these warnings (7): `Warning messages:
1: In evalq(as.numeric(as.character(consolidated_variables)), <environment>) :
  NAs introduced by coercion`. Can I just ignore these?

Comment: This warning is probably popping up since you are using `as.numeric()` on "non-numeric" values in `as.character(consolidated_variables)`. You may need to check that manually (I wouldn't be able to comment anything concrete unless you replicate this error using small sample data and share the same using `dput(df)`).

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` we can try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(country) %>% 
       mutate(Tax = taxrevenue-lag(taxrevenue))


  # A tibble: 7 x 6
  # Groups:   country [3]
  country    year taxrevenue   VAT   CIT   Tax
  <chr>     <int>      <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Angola     2006       1000   750   250    NA
2 Albania    1998       1000   750   250    NA
3 Albania    2002       1500  1125   375   500
4 Albania    2005       1200   900   300  -300
5 Argentina  1984       1900  1425   475    NA
6 Argentina  1991       1400  1050   350  -500
7 Argentina  1995       1600  1200   400   200
```

## Update

```
df %>%
 group_by(country) %>%
 mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(d = . - lag(.))) %>% select(-year_d) %>% 
 rename_at(vars(ends_with("_d")), funs(paste("d", gsub("_d", "", .), sep = "") )) %>% 
 head(n=5)

    # A tibble: 5 x 8
    # Groups:   country [3]
    country    year taxrevenue   VAT   CIT dtaxrevenue  dVAT  dCIT
    <fct>     <int>      <int> <int> <int>       <int> <int> <int>
      1 Angola     2006       1000   750   250          NA    NA    NA
    2 Albania    1998       1000   750   250          NA    NA    NA
    3 Albania    2002       1500  1125   375         500   375   125
    4 Albania    2005       1200   900   300        -300  -225   -75
    5 Argentina  1984       1900  1425   475          NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your help! Any idea how to extend the last line to a more general solution for the whole df?

Comment: You are most welcome. You can try list all variables inside `mutate` like `mutate(Tax = taxrevenue-lag(taxrevenue), VAT = VAT-lag(VAT), ...)` OR use `mtate_at` as in @Prem answer

Comment: It's our pleasure

Comment: I incorporated your answer but realised that it removes the `year` column from the df. Is there any way to prevent this? I tried to covert the year to string before applying the solution but that did not work.

Comment: @TomKisters just remove `select(-year) %>% ` form the chain. `select(x)` select x column from the df, while `select(-x)` select all columns in the df except x

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, so to be totally clear: by simply removing `select(-year) %>% ` the year column comes back but the rest stays the same?

Comment: @TomKisters I was asking myself the same question. Actually, it should be `select(-year_d) %>%`  as `mutate_if ` compute the lag for it, since the year is numeric. Thanks for pointing that out, I will update my answer. Yes the rest stays the same.

Comment: I will stick to just removing the `select(-year) %>%` haha;) The `year_d` might actually come in handy if I will decide to use interpolation!

Answer (score 1):

One version with data.table.

```
# make data
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
    country = c("Angola", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina"),
    year    = c(2006, 1998, 2002, 2005, 1984, 1991, 1995),
    tax     = c(1000, 1000, 1500, 1200, 1900, 1400, 1600),
    vat     = c(750,   750, 1125,  900, 1425, 1050, 1200),
    cit     = c(250,   250,  375,  300,  475,  350,  400)
)

# get lagged taxes
dt <- dt[order(country, year)]
dt[ , lag_tax := shift(tax), by=country]
dt[ , lag_vat := shift(vat), by=country]
dt[ , lag_cit := shift(cit), by=country]

# calculate tax differences
dt[ , dtax := tax - lag_tax]
dt[ , dvat := vat - lag_vat]
dt[ , dcit := cit - lag_cit]
```

If you needed to do this for many columns, use `lapply` and `.SD`:

```
# get lagged cols
dt[ , paste0(names(dt)[3:5], "_lag") := lapply(.SD, shift), by=country, .SDcols=3:5]

# or go straight to differences
dt[ , paste0(names(dt)[3:5], "_diff") := lapply(.SD, function(x) x - shift(x)), by=country, .SDcols=3:5]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry for the late response. Would it be possible to generalise this answer to a large dataset?

Comment: How so? The current solution would work just fine for a dataset with many more countries and years.

Comment: I mean that I would, for various reasons, prefer not to type in every column (over 150) separately, but rather something that tells it to create a lag variable for every column. Something like: df[, 3:ncol(df)]

Comment: See addition to answer above